# How to update names field nested in an array in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have this object and I'd like to update the name field "field" of all the document in the collections. I read the mongodb documentation and it says `$rename` doesn't work in this case. I should execute a forEach but I don't know how which command use

```
{
  "name": "foo"
  "array": [
   "object": {
     "field": "name"
   }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it manually:

```
db.collection.find().forEach(function(doc) { 
    if (doc.array) { 
        doc.array.forEach(function(edoc) { 
            if (edoc.object) { 
                    doc.object.new_field = edoc.object.field
                    delete edoc.object.field 
            }
        })
        db.test.update({ "_id" : doc._id }, doc)
    }
})
```

This should get you started. It handles missing or empty `array` arrays, but not an `array` value of the wrong type, or an `object` value of the wrong type.

Answer (score -3):

$rename modifier for update Ops should work (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/rename/)

Imagine a collection like yours:

```
{
    "name": "foo",
    "array":[
        {"field": "name" }
    ]
}
```

You will be able to do something like this:

```
db.rename.update({},{$rename:{"name":"newName"}});
```

And the document will be as follows:
    {
        "newName": "foo",
        "array":[
            {"field": "name" }
        ]
    }

In order to update all the collection you should use the multi option as follows:

```
db.rename.update({},{$rename:{"name":"newName"}}, {multi:true})
```

Regards